# JBoss community v. Redhat versions

Tags: jboss, redhat

How can I tell if a system is running the Redhat JBoss EAP (which requires a subscription) or the free community edition?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the beginning of `JBOSS_HOME/server/<profile>/log/boot.log` ,for the **community edition**:

```
14:17:43,333 INFO  [AbstractServer] Starting: JBossAS [6.0.0.Final "Neo"
```

For **EAP**:

```
09:53:55,419 INFO [Server] Release ID: JBoss [EAP] 4.3.0.GA
```